# php javascript change innerHTML with select value from table

Tags: javascript, php, innerhtml

I've got a form with a input field(FIELD1).  When the user types in FIELD1 it filters values in FIELD2.  Then they click on FIELD2 and it display's the value selected via javascript (this tutorial:  http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php).  The problem I'm having is that the value of FIELD2 is the companyID in the table - how do I include the javascript to lookup the company name from the table.  Picture attached.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText2(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('cv_bus').value;
    document.getElementById('boldStuff2').innerHTML = userInput;
    document.getElementById('filterTxt').innerHTML = userInput;
}
</script>


<table style="width:500px;border:1px solid #000;">
<tr><td>2</td><td>Type in the box below to narrow the list of names:</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="text" name="filterTxt" id="filterTxt" tabindex="2" style="width: 400px"></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><p>SELECTED: <font color=red><b id='boldStuff2'>NONE</b> </p></font></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>Select the apropriate name:</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><select autocomplete="off" id="cv_bus" name="cv_bus" size=15 tabindex="2" style="width: 400px" onclick="changeText2()">
<?php 
    include 'cv_con.php';
    $get = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cv_companies order by compname");
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cv_companies order by compname");
    //$option = '';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['compname'].'</option>';
    }
?>
<?php echo $option; ?></select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var el = document.getElementById('cv_bus');
var text = el.options[el.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```

Try this example, first get the ID then access to the options label.

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
var userInput = document.getElementById('cv_bus').value;
```

with

```
var userInput = cv_bus.options[cv_bus.selectedIndex].text;
```

another way is pass this in function:

```
<select autocomplete="off" id="cv_bus" name="cv_bus" size=15 tabindex="2" style="width: 400px" onclick="changeText2(this);">

function changeText2(selObj){
    var userInput = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById('boldStuff2').innerHTML = userInput;
    document.getElementById('filterTxt').innerHTML = userInput;
}
```

Comment: @Sameera Thilakasiri Answer is more reliable. But with id its also working.